# Why is it not a good practice to throw and catch messages within a single process?

Tags: camunda

Many times I saw people mentioning that it is not a good practice to throw and catch messages within a single process. Single Process Messaging (A throw sending a message to a catch inside of the same process) being problematic, but why? Could someone please explain, what could be the issues if we do so?

Thanks